# Marker icon not show on jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

When I load this page into a div (using jQuery.load()), marker icon is not showed. The icon will show after reloaded the page. Is that caused map not initialized when i pass it into placeMarker function? How to solve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var markers = new Array();      
var marker;

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.19605333333333,106.79684);
    var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
        fillPositionForm(event.latLng);
    }); 
}

function placeMarker(location) {
    if ( marker ) {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: true
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
        clearOverlays();
        fillPositionForm(event.latLng);
    });
}

function fillPositionForm(location){            
    jQuery("#latitude").val(location.lat());
    jQuery("#longitude").val(location.lng());
}

function clearOverlays() {
    if (markers) {
        for (i in markers) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    initialize();
    jQuery("#frmAddPoi").validate({
        messages: {
            latitude: "Please click on map to select poi center position",
            longitude: "Please click on map to select poi center position",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            return postForm(form, "savepoi", "listcustopoi", false, false);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="map_canvas" class="widgettitle" style="height:240px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attaching `placeMarker` to map.click event listener.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
    fillPositionForm(event.latLng);
});
```

You need to load it after map is called.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
     placeMarker(myLatlng);
```

See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y7HCV/)

Comment: placeMarker(myLatlng); function will execute when user click on map, it will create a marker on user click. myLatlng will get undefined error on your code. Or maybe I miss understanding?

Comment: In Question `When I load this page into a div (using jQuery.load()), marker icon is not showed.....How to solve it.` My answer solves this. If you want the marker to show when the user clicks map your origonal code does this. I have tested both codes with no errors.What is your exact problem?.

Answer (score -1):

You should have your function Initialize() called after your load() success. It's better to have your javascript in your main page, not in the page loaded.
Or you can use an iFrame, the easiest way.

Comment: `iframe`?  Explain more... AFAIK, the map is already inside an `iframe` owned by Google... and you propose nesting that inside another one?  He simply needs to follow the docs and load in the proper order.